# how to add video in iframe src from project directory

Tags: html, url, video

I have a video in my Project directory under folder name `Video` and Video name `Sapno.MP4`.Now i have to add this Video in my webpage . Currently i have added you tube video in it and it is getting displayed and played properly but now i want to replace it with my local project directory video.

Here is the HTML that i am using..

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sP4NMoJcFd4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
```

Please help me to get it corrected ..Thanks..

Comment: @Novocaine I tried adding `//Video//Sapno.MP4` but its not working ..

Comment: If you are using HTML5, then you can use the HTML5 `video` tag. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp If not, then you need your own player embedded into your webpage.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I am using `iframe ` for adding video

Comment: @Novocaine R u helping me sir ?

Comment: If you want to use the iframe, then you need to create a new .html page and add that to the iframe src.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Is this the only way ? If yes How can i do it ?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I replaced the URL and now getting error as Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1whG-9BjsQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Answer (score 0):

set the `SRC` attribute to `Videos/Sanpo.mp4`.

Another option is to use the HTML5 video tag, in which case you will have to use the above source tag anyways.